# Any way to use Lenovo Fingerprint Manager instead of Windows Hello on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, thinkpad, fingerprint

I just got a new Thinkpad T Series and upgraded from Windows 7.1 to Windows 10. Now when trying to Install Lenovo Fingerprint Manager Pro I get the message that this version of Windows won't support this software, and the Programm exits.

Compatiblity modes: 7/8 already tried, no success. Can't install the software.

Any idea how to get Lenovo Fingerprint Manager installed and use this instead of Windows Hello?

**Update:** [This](https://superuser.com/a/1088372/398296) might be a solution, but I won't test it since I need my nodebook every day and can't risk any downtime.

Comment: Whats wrong with Windows Hello if I may ask?

Comment: Sure. You need to setup a Pin-code before you can use fingerprints. Pin-codes allow digits only, so it is a huge security risk in my opinion. Lenovo Fingerprint manager also does use this informations for alot other stuff which is very important for me.

Comment: The pin is only valid on that device but Lenovo software has to have support for Windows 10 and it doesn't

Comment: Well @Ramhound I know the Pin is for this device only, but it still unlocks the system. It is a security risk to use numbers only for authentication. Yes, this specific software isn't supported by lenovo yet, but my biggest problem is that you can't use fingerprints as long as you don't setup a Pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far no other way than using a pretty long code of numbers to use fingerprints.

Answer (score 3):

[ThinkVantage Fingerprint Software](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds036923) version 6.0 for Windows 8.1 (64-bit) can be installed to Windows 10. After installation it runs independently.

Comment: This might be a solution, but to be honest, I'm afraid of trying around here because I need the notebook every day. I'll add a hint to this possible solution.

Comment: I can confirm - just remove any Windows Hello integrations and PIN code and install and configure ThinkVantage solution. Works perfectly!

Comment: Important: after installing ThinkVantage Fingerprint Software it's necessary to disable Windows Hello credentials provider as fingerprint sensor has only one storage for prints and Windows will use its own fingerprint software by default.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/de-DE/9c23976a-3e2b-4b71-9f19-83ee3df0848b/how-to-disable-additional-credential-providers can be used to disable Windows Hello provider and set default to ThinkVantage.

Just in case:
{BEC09223-B018-416D-A0AC-523971B639F5} - GUID of WinBio
{18CBEEAA-6708-41A1-9379-D08915333CF2} - GUID of UPEK (ThVa)

Comment: WinBio provider should be disabled and ThinkVantage (aka UPEK) should be set as default for our user in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\UserTile
See https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/set-default-sign-in-option-in-windows-10.html for help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I run a first gen X1 Carbon. I've installed the fingerprint software successfully by installing it from the Lenovo System Update software. Have you tried that?

Comment: It runs for me too, but I need to activate microsoft hello. Otherwise my fingerprint scanner doesn't seem to work. Did you setted up microsoft hello?

Comment: I did have to setup Hello now that I think about it. I saw your comment about PINs above. I thought the same thing at first and then read about how it works. The PIN can only be entered from the machine itself and actually allows for more security by not permitting a remote user to authenticate with it. It's a way of adding additional security while also adding ease of use for the user.

Comment: As far as I know the PIN can be entered only from the machine itself is correctly, but in case the attacker is right in front of your device, this pin makes it less the secure. For remote reasons it's more secure then before, thats correct. But The gap for the case "attacker got the device" is a way to risky for my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Side-note for those discussing the use of PINs . . . there is actually an option to include letters as well as numbers in your Windows Hello PIN, so it can actually be just like any password.